# document ready function bootstrapValidator run code in button_click on Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, buttonclick, document-ready, autopostback

I have validation code: (it's work correctly)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainform').bootstrapValidator({
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    ku: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'test2'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 11,
                                message: 'test'
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
            });
        });
```

but when in DropDownList with `AutoPostBack="true"` I change selected item this JS code runs:

```
Protected Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button.Click
```

However this runs the click event for each `asp:buton` on site.

How can I prevent this ?

I want run `button_Click` only when I click this button.

Dropdownlist code:

```
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="produkt" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="produkt_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>



   Protected Sub produkt_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles produkt.SelectedIndexChanged
        data_ofertowania.Text = Request.Form(data_ofertowania.UniqueID)
        Dim myConn As SqlConnection
        Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
        myConn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT '' as podprodukt UNION SELECT DISTINCT [nazwa_podprodukt] FROM [dbo].[slo_produkt] WHERE [active]='True' and grupa='" & grupa_produktow.SelectedValue & "' and nazwa_produkt='" & produkt.SelectedValue & "'"
        myConn.Open()
        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
        podprodukt.DataSource = myReader
        podprodukt.DataValueField = "podprodukt"
        podprodukt.DataTextField = "podprodukt"
        podprodukt.DataBind()
        myConn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: button_click only runs for the buttons defined in the Handles, or where a button would explicitly define the handler for the buttons.  It doesn't just fire button_Click handler for every button unless you specify it, but every asp:Button control does postback to the server, unless you use JavaScript to prevent it....

Comment: I doubt the code you shown is in problem, show us the <DropDownList /> see if there is something wrong in it

Comment: I add <DropDownList /> code, but I have this same behavior with othert controls, e.g. RadioButtonList

Comment: When I remove JS code everything works fine